# checkbox validation in vuejs 2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a problem creating two `checkbox` in javascript and checking if none is clicked, an error appears in the form field, and at least one `checkbox` must be clicked, if one is clicked there will not be an error in the form field .

I'm using VueJs 2

```
<div class="d-flex">
  <v-checkbox
    v-model="checkboxOptionHydro"
    :rules="checkboxPermissionRules.required"
    class="ml-3 secondary--text"
    label="Hydro"
    color="accent"
    required
  />
  <v-checkbox
    v-model="checkboxOptionWind"
    :rules="checkboxPermissionRules.required"
    class="ml-3 secondary--text"
    label="Wind"
    color="accent"
    required
  />
</div>;
```

```
data: () => ({
checkboxPermissionRules: { required: v => !!v || "error you need to choose one of the options" },
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to use your v-model reference in whatever function submits your form. For example, if you button that submits your form, add an v-on:click to your function. The validation can happen inside that function before the form gets submitted.

```
<button v-on:click="submitForm">Submit<button>
```

In your methods:

```
function submitForm(){
 //validation 
 if (!checkboxOptionHydro && !checkboxOptionWind){
  //add error to data
  this.checkboxError = true;
 } 
}
```

And then just add an element(p tag with red font or whatever) under the checkbox in your form to display the error if this.checkboxError is true.
Does that help?